# Convert a hex ECDSA private key to PEM format (OpenSSL)

Tags: openssl, hex, pem, ecdsa, der

I'm trying to use this ECDSA private key provided by ietf.org in OpenSSL (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6979#appendix-A.2.8):

```
x = 09A4D6792295A7F730FC3F2B49CBC0F62E862272F
```

I'd like to convert this hex key into the PEM format so that I can use it in OpenSSL for ECDSA sign/verification. From my research there is the possibility of creating a DER file by concatenating a header with my binary key and then converting it to PEM.

I generated a DER file with the result of an ECDSA header (first 7 bytes, from what I've seen, could be wrong) + my key in binary like this:

```
# converted my key to binary
xxd -r -p key.hex key.bin

# generated a key just to get its header
openssl ecparam -name sect163k1 -genkey -noout -out tempkey.pem
openssl ec -in tempkey.pem -outform der -out tempkey.der         
head -c 7 tempkey.der > header.der

# concatenated the header with my key
cat header.der key.bin > key.der
```

Then ran the command to convert the key to PEM format:

```
openssl ec -in key.der -inform der -out key.pem
```

But this last steps fails with:

```
Could not read private key from key.der
unable to load Key
```

Comment: The OpenSSL statement generates a PEM encoded key in SEC1 format, which apart from the raw private key also contains the OID and the raw public key. If you remove these, you must also correct the length information. It may be easier to also replace the raw public key (= the concatenation of Ux and Uy) in addition to the raw private key (the raw public key is at the very end). Note that for sect163k1 the private key, Ux and Uy are each 21 bytes in size (if they are shorter, they must be padded from the front with 0x00 values).

Comment: This is what the key from the reference looks like in SEC1 format, PEM encoded: https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MFMCAQEEFQCaTWeSKVp_cw_D8rScvA9i6GInL6AHBgUrgQQAAaEuAywABAea7gkNsF7CUtXLRFLzVr4Zik_5bweC4pY03cmjHvQDhuiWuqGLU6-low. A check is possible, e.g. with *openssl ec -check -in <path to key>*.